# Foundation checkbox value error

Tags: javascript, checkbox, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation 4 framework and I added a custom form into my page.

HTML:

```
<label for="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> <p> CHECKBOX TEST</p>
</label>
```

JS:

```
if($('#checkbox2').is(":checked")){
   isnewsletter = 1;
} else {
   isnewsletter = 0;
}
```

and even this

```
newsletter = $('#checkbox2').val(),
```

isn't working.
How can I check, if my checkbox is checked?

Comment: it's an $.ajax({}); posting. in data I'm doing this { newsletter: isnewsletter, ..... }

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#checkbox2').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
     console.log(1);
  } else {
     console.log(0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First checking works fine. If you add `checked="checked"` to your checkbox `isnewsletter` will be `1`.
P.S. You don't mention any other way how you tick checkbox in your program. Your checkbox is not displayed on the page, so you cannot tick it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite clear whether OP wants to check if checkbox is :checked on change, at any random moment during interaction on a page, or on validation using the Foundation 4 Abide library. I've run into issues with the custom form and toggling hidden fields, as well as validating hidden fields, and the custom form doesn't help. However, I've worked around it, but those are different questions.

The "custom" form does by default hide the input and create a span after it that gets the class "checked", and the property on the hidden checkbox doesn't visually appear in Chrome's developer toolbar (I haven't checked FireBug to see if that property appears). However, if you write a code based check of the property of the checkbox, it will return 'true':

```
$("#checkbox2").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
    console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
    // set up if using either method above, your choice.
    if( $(this).prop('checked')) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Or you can check the span.checkbox.custom directly after the input for the class "checked":

```
$("#checkbox2").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).next().hasClass("checked"));
    // set up if statement using that logic above:
    if($(this).next().hasClass("checked") ) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Use the same logic to check whether the checkbox is checked at any point, just don't bother with the .change() function. These will return true if the box is checked:

```
$("#checkbox2").next().hasClass("checked");
$("#checkbox2").is(":checked");
$("#checkbox2").prop("checked");
```

Foundation 4 didn't have validation built into Abide, you'd have to add it in.

This requires adjusting Abide.

I answered that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096609/foundation-4-3-2-abide-doesnt-validate-checkboxes).