# Foundation 4.3.2 Abide Doesn't Validate Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox, zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation 4.3.2 Abide validation doesn't validate checkboxes.

Though it would be relatively easy to write my own custom validation, it would be even better if I could update the library to validate, so that other users/developers at this massive institution I work at could also use the tools, without having to go digging for custom scripts.

How to update Abide to make checkbox validation work, without having to update to Foundation 5?—This website belongs to a massive organization, and upgrading will take months, manpower, and a lot of budget, none of which we have.

Here's example code:

```
<form id="form-name" data-abide="ajax">
    <label for="print-checkbox"><input id="print-checkbox" type="checkbox" required name="print-checkbox"> <strong>Blah Blah Blah Label Text</strong>
        <small class="error"><span class="icon-exclamation-sign"></span> A warning that only appears if the form doesn't validate.</small>
    </label>
    <input id="print-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button small radius">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form-name').on('valid invalid submit', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.type === "valid") {
        alert("returns valid");
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And of course drafting this question had me start thinking about some solutions, and I figured one out that works.

First off, [I integrated in a fix for Abide 4.3.2 that fixed the incorrect validation of hidden required fields.](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3576)

Next, I added in some logic to support checkboxes.

Finally, I duplicated the radio validation, made a couple slight changes, and voila! Checkbox validation.

Here's the function from the GIT link above, modified to include checkboxes. Note the addition of `is_checkbox...` and `} else if (is_checkbox && required) {`:

```
check_validation_and_apply_styles : function (el_patterns) {
  var count = el_patterns.length,
      validations = [];

  for (var i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var el = el_patterns[i][0],
        required = el_patterns[i][2],
        value = el.value,
        is_radio = el.type === "radio",
        is_checkbox = el.type === "checkbox",
        valid_length = (required) ? (el.value.length > 0) : true,
        isVisible = $(el).is(":visible");
    if (isVisible) {
        if (is_radio && required) {
          validations.push(this.valid_radio(el, required));
        } else if (is_checkbox && required) {
          validations.push(this.valid_checkbox(el, required));
        } else {
          if (el_patterns[i][1].test(value) && valid_length ||
            !required && el.value.length < 1) {
            $(el).removeAttr('data-invalid').parent().removeClass('error');
            validations.push(true);
          } else {
            $(el).attr('data-invalid', '').parent().addClass('error');
            validations.push(false);
          }
        }
    }
  }

  return validations;
},
```

And then below, I duplicated the `valid_radio : function (el, required)` and repurposed it for the checkboxes:

```
valid_radio : function (el, required) {
  var name = el.getAttribute('name'),
      group = document.getElementsByName(name),
      count = group.length,
      valid = false;

  for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {
    if (group[i].checked) valid = true;
  }

  for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {
    if (valid) {
      $(group[i]).removeAttr('data-invalid').parent().removeClass('error');
    } else {
      $(group[i]).attr('data-invalid', '').parent().addClass('error');
    }
  }

  return valid;
},

valid_checkbox : function (el, required) {
  var name = el.getAttribute('name'),
      group = document.getElementsByName(name),
      count = group.length,
      valid = false;
  for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {
    if (group[i].checked) valid = true;
  }

  for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {
    if (valid) {
      $(group[i]).removeAttr('data-invalid').parent().removeClass('error');
    } else {
      $(group[i]).attr('data-invalid', '').parent().addClass('error');
    }
  }

  return valid;
}
```

Bam. Checkbox validation with Zurb Foundation Abide 4.2.3

Comment: Exactly what I needed.
You are an awesome person.  :)

Comment: @edcincy Glad to help! If this was helpful to you, please make sure to upvote!

Comment: Seems amazing that I'd have to ask this, but is there checkbox validation with Abide in 5.4.7--specifically, for a single checkbox in a form that has nothing else to validate? This appears to be an issue.

Comment: @cbmtrx foundation 5 uses abide, and it has checkbox validation. Look at this page, you can see their example right at the top: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

Comment: Right, I saw that example, except theirs are validated as part of a larger form. The issue arises (from what I can garner) when the form is just a single checkbox. Any insights?

Comment: @cbmtrx I see the misunderstanding: the issue in Foundation 4.x that I was trying to fix was that Abide didn't validate checkboxes (or hidden fields) at all. AND, it also didn't validate groups of checkboxes, or groups of radials. Foundation 5 DOES validate checkboxes, so you should be ok. The link I posted earlier to their docs is a method to confirm: unselect their checkboxes and hit submit. They'll turn red. If you view source, you'll see the "required" attribute. So you should be ok with Abide 5.4.7. AND you should be ok if your form has ONLY one checkbox; it's that flexible. :)

Comment: We figured out that it was a DOM structure/precedence thing: we discovered that we had to put our Abide validation (for this particular form) AFTER the `$(document).foundation('reflow');` statement. For whatever reason, this solved our issue. Thanks.